# Выполнение запроса 2 раза Modx

Tags: modx

Делаю свой снипет. Пишу код для вставки в базу

```
$res=$modx->prepare("insert into modx_subscribe (email) values ('$email')");
$res->execute();
```

Он почему то 2 раза вставляет в базу: 1 раз с пустым email, второй раз - с нужным. Почему так происходит?

Comment: А точно не вызываете снипет 2 раза, с параметрами и без?

Comment: нет, вот так он вызывается - [[!AjaxForm?&snippet=`subscribe`&form=`form_subscribe`]]

Comment: Попробуйте вызывать снипет без AjaxForm, у меня подозрение, что ваша страница перегружается и получается двойной вызов снипета